# Google Home application support

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-assist-api, google-smart-home

I have a device which I want to control with Google Home.
Device also can be controlled via mobile app.
It will be a commercial device so many users have different devices and, of course, I can recognise them in my mobile app.
I read documentation about Action and Home Graph, but it is still not clear how I can integrate my device/app with google home in the same way as, for example, Hue is integrated.
I could not find where I can "register" my device/app with google so it will be shown in supported devices.

What I want to achieve is the following:
User gets device, installs the app, connects it device to the app. *<- this already works.*
Then user goes to google home integrations, selects my platform and he is ready to go.

Maybe someone can push me to the right direction where to start?

Answer (score 1):

The [smart home documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) provides the content to help you get started, along with [several codelabs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/codelabs) to learn about the webhook fomat.

When you are developing your action, through the Actions Console, you will be able to see your service in the full service list as "[test] Your project name". Once your integration is ready, you submit it to be published in the full list of services.